# Finding and echoing anchor tags in a php file

Tags: php, tags, find, anchor, echo

I have searched a lot for this but have not yet found anything that works...

I would like to find all the anchor tags in another php file and echo their names (with an href to their location in the document).

For example, I have this in one file:

```
<a name="test"></a>
```

and would like to find all of them using some code in my main php file and print them all...

Here's what I've tried:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($content);
    foreach( $dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $node ) {
        echo $node->getAttribute( 'name' );
    }
```

I know it's not exactly super specific but yeah, thanks.

**EDIT:** How about a way to find and echo anchors on the current page?

look here for the actual site: http://robertwbooth.co.uk

Comment: The whole DOMdocument stuff loading the file in and searching but it doesn't seem to work; loads of different ways but none are really specific enough and/or just don't seem to work.

Comment: Loading DOMDocument and searching should work.  Just find all the `a` tag elements with http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php and then check each of their name attributes

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
$html = file_get_html("http://xxxxxx/support/content-entry/create-anchor-tags/");
$anchor = array();

foreach ( $html->find("a") as $link ) {
    if ($link->href === false) {
        $key = $link->id ? $link->id : ($link->name ? $link->name : false);
        if (! $key)
            continue;
        if (isset($anchor[$link->id])) {
            $anchor[$link->id] = array_merge($anchor[$link->id], array("name" => $link->name,"id" => $link->id));
        } else {
            $anchor[$link->id] = array("name" => $link->name,"id" => $link->id);
        }
    } else {
        if (strpos($link->href, "#") === 0) {

            if (isset($anchor[substr($link->href, 1)])) {
                $anchor[substr($link->href, 1)] = array_merge($anchor[substr($link->href, 1)], array("text" => $link->plaintext));
            } else {
                $anchor[substr($link->href, 1)] = array("text" => $link->plaintext);
            }
        }
    }
}

var_dump($anchor);
```

Output

```
array
  'id507d815fd9383' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'id507d815fd9383' (length=15)
      'id' => string 'id507d815fd9383' (length=15)
      'text' => string 'Visit the Useful Tips Section' (length=29)
  'id507d815fd93a3' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'id507d815fd93a3' (length=15)
      'id' => string 'id507d815fd93a3' (length=15)
      'text' => string 'Visit the Useful Tips Section' (length=29)
  'id507d815fd93bc' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'id507d815fd93bc' (length=15)
      'id' => string 'id507d815fd93bc' (length=15)
      'text' => string 'Visit the Useful Tips Section' (length=29)
  'id507d815fd93d3' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'id507d815fd93d3' (length=15)
      'id' => string 'id507d815fd93d3' (length=15)
      'text' => string 'Visit the Useful Tips Section' (length=29)
  'id507d815fd93eb' => 
    array
      'name' => string 'id507d815fd93eb' (length=15)
      'id' => string 'id507d815fd93eb' (length=15)
      'text' => string 'Visit the Useful Tips Section' (length=29)
  'id507d815fd9404' => 
    array

.......... so many more
```